# how to deal with response time for firebase auth state

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to minimize the amount of time it takes for my web application to successfully check if its firebase authenticated but my 'auth state object' doesnt seem to be working correctly on my template (the appropriate sections on the template dont appear at all)

My aimed solution would be to store the auth state in local storage so if someone reopens the web application there isn't a choppy load for the user auth section of the page. Can anyone help or lean me towards a different/better solution?

My app component contains the below in its constructor:

```
  this.authService.authListener();
```

header.component.ts  - where I want to keep track of my user Auth

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  authObj: Observable<any>;
  constructor(public sideNavService: SideNavService, private accountService: AccountService, private authService: AuthenticationService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authObj = this.authService.getAuthState();
  }
}
```

header.component.html

```
  <div *ngIf="authObj | async as authObj">
            <div *ngIf="!authObj.authenticated" class="header-ctas" fxHide.lt-md>
                <button mat-button [routerLink]="['/account/create']" class="btn-register">Register</button>
                <button mat-button [routerLink]="['/account/login']" class="btn-login">Account Login</button>
                <mat-icon routerLink="['/']">shopping_cart</mat-icon>
            </div>
            <div *ngIf="authObj.authenticated" class="header-ctas" fxHide.lt-md>
                <button mat-button (click)="accountService?.logout()" class="btn-register">Logout</button>
                <mat-icon routerLink="['/']">shopping_cart</mat-icon>
            </div>
        </div>
```

My auth service has the following:

```
   public authListener() {
    let userAuthObj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userAuth'));
    if (userAuthObj && userAuthObj.authenticated) {
        this.authenticationState.next(userAuthObj);
    } else {
        this.fireAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
            localStorage.setItem('userAuth', JSON.stringify({ user: user ? user : null, authenticated: user ? true : false }));
            this.authenticationState.next(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userAuth')));
        });
    }
}

  public getAuthState() {
        return this.authenticationState.asObservable();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ngOnInit() is a lifecycle hook and it should not be used for async calls (Best practice). Instead, move the validation code to a resolver.

auth.resolver.ts

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AuthResolver implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private authservice: AuthService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot ): Observable<any>
  {
    return this.authService.getAuthState();
  }
}
```

app.routing.ts

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: '/',
        component: HeaderComponent,
        resolve: {
          authState: AuthResolver
        }
      }
    ])
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

add the resolver to your ngModule under providers:

```
 providers: [AuthResolver] //Add AuthResolver to the providers array
```

header.component.ts

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  authObj: any;
  constructor(public sideNavService: SideNavService, private accountService: AccountService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authState = this.route.snapshot.data['authState'].authenticated;
  }
}
```

For more information check the official documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve#description).

Comment: A resolver is a good approach, but I must strongly disagree with the statement that it's not the best practice to call async in ngOnInit. 

ngOnInit is the ideal starting point (not constructor) , and you absolutely should do complex processing and initial data fetching (even async). 

Read more here: 
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#oninit